# Providing an application error page in Play Framework 2.2 java?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I tried to create such a page: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGlobal
When i run the app i get:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How did you define your errorPage view? You must set it to take Throwable as parameter. Check on your tutorial's source code, here is how it's done : https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/documentation/manual/javaGuide/main/global/code/javaguide/global/errorPage.scala.html

```
@(ex:Throwable)
Custom error page
@ex.getMessage
```

Comment: thankyou that was very helpful. but it now says, `object Application is not a member of package controllers` what should it point to in routes? the Global class? or do i need an Application controller class? sorry, I inherited this system and am still not that knowdlegable of the framework.

Comment: oh i think i found it here now: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaActions
My main controller was not called Application so i was confused for a sec there.